# Query based on number of associated models

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, scopes

I'm working on a project where I need to scope a model by the number of associated models under a where clause. This is the best I could come up with:

```
Subscription.where('message_cap > ?', TextMessage.where('created_at > ?', DateTime.now.beginning_of_month).where(subscription: subscription).count)
```

But, it doesn't work because subscription is undefined. Is there any way in a rails query I can reference the model currently being hit by postgres? I think this is the SQL I'm looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM 'subscriptions' WHERE 'subscription.message_cap' > (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'text_messages' WHERE 'text_messages.subscription_id' = 'subscription.id' AND 'text_message.created_at > BEGINNINGOFMONTH')
```

This is a really, really performance critical part of my application, so I need it to run in one query if I can.

EDIT

By the way, I'm not sure if the SQL query above is valid. I just put it there to convey the idea of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following:

```
Subscription.select('subscriptions.id').
  joins(:text_messages).
  where('messages.created_at > ?', date).
  group('subscriptions.id').
  having('COUNT(*) > subscriptions.message_cap')
```

Being `date` the parameter of the query.

Note that each `Subscription` object in the result will contain only the `id` of the subscription.  To retrieve the full objects you will need a query like the following:

```
Subscription.find(ids)
```

If it is a critical part of your application you should test the query using your favorite test framework.

Comment: Maybe use `.select('subscriptions.*')` ?

Comment: Part of the problem is that the count is unique to each model as well. That's why I have `message_cap`. It's a column on the subscription model.

Comment: subscriptions.* will not work in PostgreSQL (at least) as you can't select columns which are not in the group by clause.

Comment: @DylanKarr what does message_cap stands for? you mean each subscription has a differente count limit?

Comment: It's an integer. It's just the per-basis limit on each subscription as to how many text messages they can receive.

Comment: in that case you can change  having('COUNT(\*\) > ?', count) for  having('COUNT(\*\) > subscriptions.message_cap')

Comment: I take that back. It doesn't return anything when there's any text messages, even when subscriptions.message_cap is 10.

Comment: Also, the where clause has to be modified to allow for null created_at when there are no text_messages, and the join has to be rewritten as a left join so subscriptions with no text_messages will show up.

Answer (score 0):

```
query = "SELECT * FROM 'subscriptions' WHERE 'subscription.message_cap' > (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'text_messages' WHERE 'text_messages.subscription_id' = 'subscription.id' AND 'text_message.created_at > BEGINNINGOFMONTH')"
Subscription.find_by_sql(query)
```

If that is not fast enough then you should look into caching the text messages count for each subscription. This can be done by creating a view or adding a counter column to the subscriptions table. The view is the better solution, but more involved to implement.

### Update

```
subscriptions_table = Subscription.table_name
text_messages_table = TextMessage.table_name
foreign_key = TextMessage.reflect_on_association(:subscription).foreign_key
query = "SELECT * FROM '#{subscriptions_table}' WHERE '#{subscriptions_table}.message_cap' > (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '#{text_messages_table}' WHERE '#{text_messages_table}.#{foreign_key}' = '#{subscriptions_table}.id' AND '#{text_messages_table}.created_at > #{Date.current.beginning_of_month}')"
Subscription.find_by_sql(query)
```

Comment: I'd rather not use query strings like this because my table names may change in the future. Also, I'm not sure if this query actually works.

Comment: @DylanKarr no problem, check the update for a more dynamic solution.